# Создание сервера на Java

Tags: java, сервер

Я новичок в ява, изучил основы и интересует каким образом создаются сервера на ява. Я могу написать приложение которое будет слушать определенный порт и отвечать на него по сокет соединению - является ли это сервером. Если да тогда зачем нужен Tomcat

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/69136/ на вот тебе. там томкат не нужен

Comment: Хороший вопрос для новичков...

Answer (score 4):

Сервер - это любое приложение ожидающее и обрабатывающее соединение. Так что то, что вы написали - сервер. Но, как правило, вам нужны не только сокет соединения, но и обработка http запросов. Чтобы для каждого приложения не писать свой сервер и не переписывать код в случае изменения параметров, сделали контейнеры сервлетов, такие как tomcat и jetty. Контейнеры сервлетов обрабатывают запросы и позволяют сконцентрироваться на логике приложения, а не на запросах.